# ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'collections'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from kanren import *
z = var()
x = var()
print("Value of x is:")
print(run(1,x,eq(x,z),eq(z,3))) #n desired solutions ; x,z variables
```

and the error is

ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'collections'

Any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: The library you are using is out of date. It is trying to import from `collections` instead of `collections.abc`.

Comment: collections is like a library?
because i am importing from kanran
maybe i am missing a point here, I would really appreciate if you guide me a bit

Comment: You should always avoid using `from x import *`

Comment: The `Iterator` class was moved from `collections` to `collections.abc` a long time ago, I think in Python 3.3. So the module you are trying to import is very old and won't run as is in recent versions of Python. There hasn't been a new release of `kanren` since 2016 and its PyPI page says nothing about support after Python 3.5. You may be out of luck.

Comment: If [this is the right github repo](https://github.com/pythological/kanren) then it has been updated to use collections.abc.

Answer (score 2):

Iterator can be imported from collections.abc instead of collections, on recent versions of python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).