# can't use kanren on python 3.10

Tags: python

I have this code from school work (guided).

```
from kanren import *
from kanren.core import lall
import time

def lefto(q, p, list):
    return membero((q, p), zip(list, list[1:]))
    
def nexto(q, p, list):
    return conde([lefto(q, p, list)], [lefto(p, q, list)])
    


houses = var()

rules = lall(

    (eq, (var(),var(),var(),var(),var()), houses),
    
    (lefto, (var(),var(),var(),var(), 'Hijau'), (var(),var(),var(),var(), 'Putih'), houses),
    
    (membero, ('Spanyol', var(),var(), 'Anjing', var()), houses),
    
    (membero, ('Amerika', 'Vario', var(),var(),var()), houses),
    
    
    (lefto, (var(),var(),var(),var(), 'Merah'), (var(),var(),var(),var(), 'Biru'), houses),
    
    (membero, ('Inggris',var(),'Teh',var(),var()), houses),
    
    (lefto, (var(), 'Mio', var(),var(),var()), (var(),var(),var(), 'Ikan', var()), houses),
    
    (membero, (var(), 'Beat',var(), 'Hamster', var()), houses),
    
    (membero, (var(), 'Revo', var(), var(), 'Kuning'), houses),
    
    (eq, (var(),var(),var(),var(), 'Jus', var(),var()),var(),var(), houses),
    
    (membero, ('Italia', 'SupraX', var(), var(), var()), houses),
    
    (membero, (var(), 'Vario', var(), 'Kelinci', var()), houses),
    
    (membero, (var(), 'Beat' , var(), var(), 'Putih'), houses),
    
    (membero, (var(), 'SupraX', 'Susu', var(), var()), houses),
    
    (membero, ('Prancis', var(), 'Kopi', var(), var()), houses),
    
    (membero, (var(), var(), 'Kopi', ' Kucing', var()), houses),
    
    (membero, (var(), var(), 'Air', var(), 'Hijau'), houses)
)

t0 = time.time()
solutions = run(0, houses, rules)
t1 = time.time()
dur = t1 - t0

count = len(solutions)
owner = [houses for houses in solutions[0] if 'Anjing' in houses][0][0]

print ("%i solutions in %.2f seconds" % (count, dur))
print ("The %s is the owner of the Anjing" % owner)
print ("Here are all the houses:")
for line in solutions[0]:
    print (str(line))
```

I have Python 3.10, and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SenSen\Downloads\temp\untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kanren import *
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\kanren\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from unification import (unify, reify, unifiable, var, isvar, vars, variables,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\unification\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import unify, reify
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\unification\core.py", line 2, in <module>
    from collections import Iterator
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'collections' (C:\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

I haven't tried anything. What should I do besides downloading Python 3.9?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275527/importerror-cannot-import-name-iterator-from-collections