# Kanren Problem in python -> ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'collections'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, collections, iterable, python-3.10

I am learning A.I. with python from Tutorials Point and I reached to the Logic Programming section,
here the program is of "Matching Mathematical expressions", and they consider to import the Kanren package.
here is the following code

```
from kanren import run, var, fact
from kanren.assoccomm import eq_assoccomm as eq
from kanren.assoccomm import commutative, associative
```

and here is the following error it gives me

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 from kanren import run, var, fact
      2 from kanren.assoccomm import eq_assoccomm as eq
      3 from kanren.assoccomm import commutative, associative

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kanren\__init__.py:7
      2 """
      3 kanren is a Python library for logic and relational programming.
      4 """
      5 from __future__ import absolute_import
----> 7 from unification import (unify, reify, unifiable, var, isvar, vars, variables,
      8                          Var)
     10 from .core import run, eq, conde, lall, lany
     11 from .goals import seteq, permuteq, goalify, membero

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\unification\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .core import unify, reify
      2 from .more import unifiable
      3 from .variable import var, isvar, vars, variables, Var

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\unification\core.py:2
      1 from functools import partial
----> 2 from collections import Iterator
      3 from toolz.compatibility import iteritems, map
      4 from toolz import assoc

ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'collections' (C:\Users\91997\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook for my Python code and am using Python 3.10.9 version

I read the problem where I tried using

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
```

and also did try

```
from collections.abc import Iterator
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: *from collections.abc import Iterable* is valid in Python 3.12.1

Comment: Your issue is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275527/importerror-cannot-import-name-iterator-from-collections#comment127689981_72275527). [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275527/importerror-cannot-import-name-iterator-from-collections#comment127690763_72275527) says it is already updated. Did you try running `%conda install -c conda-forge miniKanren` in your notebook and then restarting the kernel? Concerning 'I read the problem ', please reference what you are citing in future posts.

Answer (score 0):

By downloading the older versions of python
in my case I downloaded version 3.9,
and it worked and gave the output
I created a new environment of 3.9 for this following code of kanren and kept 3.10 for all my latest code